# failing to store data in local storage on table data change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

New to using [Angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#configuration) and I am unable to store data in local storage after data in the table changes.

I have read their instructions and have got their demo working in my own environment, but that is watching for change when a user types a character into an input field. I need it to watch for change in the `<tr>`/`<td>` and then store it in local storage.

When I log the value that is passed to the function it returns `null'. The data that populates the table is dynamic, changing depending on what item a user clicks on. Any idea why the data that is loaded into the table isn't being stored?

**UPDATE**

Included the service in which I gather the data on `ng-click`. The id displays in the table cell but:

- I have had to use an `<input>` inside the table cell
- No data is binded to the cell at the moment, but it needs to be
- When I refresh the page, the table headings are displayed, but the data still disappears
- Storing each individual item isn't the most efficient approach

I will label the two `html` templates I have. First one (`list-patents.htm`) is the table which displays the items. When a user clicks on an item, a second template (patent-item.htm) below the table loads into `ng-view` displaying relevant information.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'LocalStorageModule']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {

    localStorageServiceProvider
        .setPrefix('demoPrefix')

    $urlRouterProvider
      .when('', '/patents/list-patents')
      .when('/', '/patents/list-patents')
      .when('/patents', '/patents/list-patents')
      .when('/transactions', '/transactions/current-transactions')
      .otherwise('/patents/list-patents');

    $stateProvider
    .state("patents", {
        url: "/patents",
        templateUrl: "templates/patents/patent-nav.htm",
        controller: "patentListCtrl"
    })
    .state("patents.list", {
        url: "/list-patents",
        templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm",
        controller: "patentListCtrl"
    })

    .state("patents.list.item", {
        url: "/patent-item",
        templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",
        params: {
           //load of params
        },
        controller: "patentItemCtrl"
    })
}];
```

---

```
app.factory('loadPatentItemService', ['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) {

var factory = {};

    var selectedItem = null;

    factory.select = function(item) { 
        factory.storeSelect = [];
        selectedItem = item;
        factory.storeSelect.push(selectedItem)
        factory.getPatent();

        return [selectedItem];
    }

}])

app.controller('patentItemCtrl', ['$scope', 'patentTabService', 'patentCheckboxService', 'localStorageService', 'loadPatentItemService', function($scope, patentTabFactory, patentCheckboxService, localStorageService, loadPatentItemService){

        var testid = loadPatentItemService.storeSelect[0].id;

        $scope.$watch('itemStorage', function(){ //watch for change, value passed to function
            localStorageService.set('itemStorage', testid);  //set value of property (what user typed in)
            $scope.localStorageDemoValue = localStorageService.get('itemStorage');
        });

        $scope.$watch(function(){
        return localStorageService.get('itemStorage');
        }, function(){
            $scope.itemStorage = testid;
        });

}])
```

---

**list-patents.htm**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">Application No. </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">Client Ref</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">Cost now</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">Cost band end</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">Cost next</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">Renewal Date</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in patents">
                    <td ng-click="select(x)"><a ui-sref="patents.list.item({id: x.id, patentApplicationNumber: x.patentApplicationNumber, clientRef: x.clientRef, renewalStatus: x.renewalStatus, currentRenewalCost: x.currentRenewalCost, costBandEndDate: x.costBandEndDate, renewalCostNextStage: x.renewalCostNextStage, renewalDueDate: x.renewalDueDate, shortTitle: x.shortTitle, primaryApplicantName: x.primaryApplicantName, patentPublicationNumber: x.patentPublicationNumber,  title: x.title, filingDate: x.filingDate, epoPatentStatus: x.epoPatentStatus})">{{x.applicationNumber}}</a></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.clientRef"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.currentRenewalCost">$</td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.costBandEndDate"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.renewalCostNextStage"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ui-view></div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**patent-item.htm**

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-xs-center" ng-controller="patentItemCtrl">
    <h2>Application Number</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                    <td>applicationNumber</td>
                    <td>clientRef</td>
                    <td>renewalStatus</td>
                    <td>costBandEndDate</td>
                    <td>renewalCostNextStage</td>
                    <td>renewalDueDate</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in patentItem">
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="itemStorage" placeholder="Start typing..." readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.clientRef" placeholder="Start typing..." readonly></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.renewalStatus"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.costBandEndDate"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.renewalCostNextStage"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can bind `ng-model` only to an input, select or textarea. You can not bind it to a `tr` or `td`.

Comment: Ok. I have changed it so the `ng model` is attribute of one of the `<td>` and still the data isn't being stored. Or can I not even apply `ng-model` to a `<td>`?

Comment: Ignore that comment you did just tell me. Any idea how I would go about storing the data?

Comment: After you fetch your new data to update table, use the same data to store in the local storage. User action -> Fetch new data -> Update table -> Update local storage. Do all this at a single place (may be in a function).

Comment: I'll have a go at doing that now

Comment: @PrerakSola carrying on from your point yesterday, is there any chance you would be able to show an example? I have tried but failed

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you attempted and the issue you are facing with it?

Comment: Updated. I attempted a couple of other approaches but to no avail. Main issue is the table data is not being stored. It disappears when I refresh